# How to create and extend Ember.ArrayController in the pre 1.0 release

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple ember.js hello world that has just 1 route

```
(function() {

  window.PersonApp = Ember.Application.create({

    ApplicationController: Ember.ObjectController.extend({}),

    ApplicationView: Ember.View.extend({
      templateName: 'application'
    }),

    Person: Ember.Object.extend({
      username: null,
      isActive: false
    }),

    PersonController: Ember.ArrayController.extend({
      content: [],

      addPerson: function(username) {
        var person = PersonApp.Person.create({ username: username });
        this.pushObject(person);
      },

      removePerson: function(person) {
        this.removeObject(person);
      }
    }),

    AddPersonTextField: Ember.TextField.extend({
      insertNewline: function() {
        var value = this.get('value');

        if (value) {
          PersonApp.PersonController.addPerson(value);
          this.set('value', '');
        }
      }
    }),

    RemovePersonCheckbox: Ember.Checkbox.extend({
      content: null,
      change: function(event) {
        PersonApp.PersonController.removePerson(this.content);
      },
    }),

    HomeController: Ember.Controller.extend(),
    HomeView: Ember.View.extend({
      templateName: 'home'
    }),

    Router: Ember.Router.create({
      root : Ember.Route.extend({
        index: Em.Route.extend({
          route: '/',
          connectOutlets: function(router){
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('home');
          }
        })
      })
    })

  });

  $(function() {
    PersonApp.initialize(PersonApp.Router);
  });

})();
```

My html template is very basic just defining a single outlet and 1 "home" view to show users by username

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Users</title>
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}script/vendor/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}script/vendor/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
{% load templatetag_handlebars %}

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <div class="container">
  {% verbatim %}
    {{outlet}}
  {% endverbatim %}
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home">
  {% verbatim %}
  {{view PersonApp.AddPersonTextField placeholder="username"}}
    <ul>
      {{#each PersonApp.PersonController}}
        <li>
          <label>
            {{view PersonApp.RemovePersonCheckbox contentBinding="this" checkedBinding="isActive"}}
            {{username}}
          </label>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
{% endverbatim %}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
ENV = {
  CP_DEFAULT_CACHEABLE: true,
  VIEW_PRESERVES_CONTEXT: true
};
</script>

<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}script/vendor/ember-1.0.pre.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}script/app/person.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When this runs I get the error

Uncaught Error: assertion failed: an Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array. You passed PersonApp.PersonController

If I try to switch the Ember.ArrayController.extend to Ember.ArrayController.create I get an error

Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'create'

After looking around it seems the latest ember might expect me to invoke .create({}) on the ArrayController first, then .extend({}) but I can't find any good examples of this using the pre 1.0 release. Does anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong in the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fiddle that works. http://jsfiddle.net/feCYT/4/

In Ember pre, using router logic, you are **`extending`** the `ArrayController` to make `PersonApp.PersonController`.

So your `PersonApp.PersonController` is a general `Class`. You have to `create` instances of this class to work on data.

Ember with `router` does this for you, As router `initializes` it creates instances of the Controllers available at the time. So you have an instance ready for you, `PersonApp.router.personController` see the small-caps for person indicating instance.

(Its worth taking a look at `App.router' on DOM inspector)

Functins like should need some some change see commented line(this is a quick fix):

```
    AddPersonTextField: Ember.TextField.extend({
        insertNewline: function () {
            var value = this.get('value');
            if (value) {
                PersonApp.router.personController.addPerson(value);//check this
                this.set('value', '');
            }
        }
    }),
```

That being a quick fix,  actual way with routers is, the events are targeted to the router by default, from the router we delegate them to views or controllers. Dig deep into routers to find this.

**Disclaimer: This is what I think :)**

### Comment bt @Luke Melia:

> As you noted, your event handler example is not ideal. When the
>   application initializes, each controller instance will have it's
>   target property set to the router. When a view handles a browser event
>   like insertNewLine, it should translate that into a semantic action
>   sent to the router. e.g.
>   this.get('controller.target').send('addPerson', this.get('value')).
>   Then the current route can handle that 'addPerson' action to modify
>   models and controllers, which in turn will trigger data binding to
>   update views, and all will be well, without any globals.

Comment: As you noted, your event handler example is not ideal. When the application initializes, each controller instance will have it's `target` property set to the router. When a view handles a browser event like `insertNewLine`, it should translate that into a semantic action sent to the router. e.g. `this.get('controller.target').send('addPerson',  this.get('value'))`. Then the current route can handle that 'addPerson' action to modify models and controllers, which in turn will trigger data binding to update views, and all will be well, without any globals.

Comment: @sabithpocker could you point me to a post or api doc that shows this approach? I thought the convention in ember was views talk to controllers and controllers talk to state managers? (thank you!)

Comment: @ToranBillups You can take a look at the doc along with code, here is Gist with some relevant parts https://gist.github.com/3595069 my first gist not sure if it works well

Comment: Thanks for the awesome gist -explains a lot. One last question - does using the action helpers mean 2 way binding still works or that only 1 way

Comment: I don't understand that question well, action helpers are not anyway directly associated with any bindings. Action helpers registers events and delegates them to specified target, actually where are you getting confused?.  Also here is a slide by @LukeMelia http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/08/23/architecting-ember-js-apps/ that might be of interest to you.

Comment: Ah very cool- I think what I found was early ember with bindAttr stuff (not action helpers at all). I'll dig into this link as you suggested (thanks again)